# getting error when applied WHERE clause on a model(parent) and then gets its related model(child) data in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a User model which is a parent and Project model which is a child. I created a one-to-many relationship between these two like below.

User Model:

```php
    class User extends Authenticatable
      {
       use Notifiable;

       /**
       * The attributes that are mass assignable.
       *
       * @var array
       */
       protected $fillable = [
         'username', 'email', 'password',
       ];
       /**
       * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
       *
       * @var array
       */
       protected $hidden = [
         'password', 'remember_token',
       ];

       /**
       * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
       *
       * @var array
       */
       protected $casts = [
         'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
       ];

       public function projects(){
          return $this->hasMany('App\Project', 'user_id');
       }
    }
```

Project Model:

```php
    class Project extends Model
    {
       // Table Name
       protected $table = 'projects';
       //Primary Key
       protected $primaryKey = 'project_id';
       // Timestamps
       public $timestamps = true;

       protected $guarded = [];

       public function user(){
          return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
       }
    }
```

when applying where clause on user model and then getting its related projects:

```php
    class HomeController extends Controller
    {
        public function createProject(Request $request){
           $client = User::where('email', $request->input('client'))->projects;
        }
    }
```

getting error

```php
   Exception
   Property [projects] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.
```

but when doing

```php
    $client = User::find(id)->projects;
```

above query is giving me results.

Result Expected: i want to get the User model data by WHERE() clause instead of Find() clause and then gets its related projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Error Says that you dont have property in the `Builder`

```
 $client = User::where('email', $request->input('client'))->projects;
```

try this

```
$client = User::with('projects')->where('email', $request->input('client'))->first()->projects;
```

here we are getting the **user with the specific email** and loading the realtion and here you **get the relation as object**

Answer (score 0):

```
class HomeController extends Controller
    {
        public function createProject(Request $request){


     $client = User::with('projects')->where('id');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of your issue is that you have not yet retrieved any users. Before calling `first()` or `get()` on the query builder, you are limited to functions of the query builder.

Short version: call `first()` before accessing the projects

```
 $client = User::query()
     ->where('email', $request->input('client'))
     ->first()
     ->projects;
```

Optional: add `with('projects')` to eager load the projects. This doesn't add any performance bonus in your case though, as you are only loading a single model.

Answer (score 0):

In HomeController this line will retrun collection of array.... In simple words it will return multiple records....
           $client = User::where('email', $request->input('client'))->projects;

As you want single record use first (). To retrive single record... It will retrun first matching record...

```
$client = User::where('email', $request->input('client'))->first()->projects;
```